# How can I create a JSON Schema for array of blocks of different types

Tags: jsonschema

I would like to define a JSON schema for a list of blocks, where each block can be of a different type, and per block there is a different set of parameters. So for example:

```json
{
    "class": "bg-white text-black",
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "countdown",
            "parameters": {
                "title": "LIMITED TIME OFFER",
                "timeleft_ms": 57600000
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "soundcloud",
            "parameters": {
                "title": "Here Are 10 great sounds!",
                "description": "These are great sounds",
                "playlistid": "aaaaa",
                "secret_token": "123456"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "parameters": {
                "lines": [
                    "Line 1",
                    "Line 2"
                ],
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "checkout_button",
            "parameters": {
                "title": "YES! I WANT THE SOUNDS",
                "class": "bg-blue-600 text-white"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "parameters": {
                "lines": [
                    "Line 1",
                    "Line 2"
                ],
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

Where each type of block (like text) can appear more than once, and in any order.

Restructuring the JSON is also no problem, as long as I can get IntelliSense per type of block.

**UPDATE**

@Jason Desrosiers I tried your approach, simplified the JSON to:

```json
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "countdown",
      "title": "LIMITED TIME OFFER"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "line": "Hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

and implemented the schema:

```json
{
    "type": "object",
    "properties": {
      "blocks": {
        "type": "array",
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/block"
        }
      }
    },
    "definitions": {
      "block": {
        "allOf": [
          {
            "if": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "const": "countdown"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "type", "title"
              ]
            },
            "then": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/countdown"
            }
          },
          {
            "if": {
              "type": "object",
              "properties": {
                "type": {
                  "const": "text"
                }
              },
              "required": [
                "type", "line"
              ]
            },
            "then": {
              "$ref": "#/definitions/text"
            }
          }
        ]
      },
      "countdown": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "title": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      },
      "text": {
        "type": "object",
        "properties": {
          "line": {
            "type": "string"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

And it validates! (Checked at https://www.jsonschemavalidator.net/), but the following validates as well:

```json
{
  "blocks": [
    {
      "type": "countdown",
      "title_abc": "LIMITED TIME OFFER"
    },
    {
      "type": "text",
      "line_abc": "Hello"
    }
  ]
}
```

Any way to make sure you can just use the properties defined?

Answer (score 0):

Use `items` to describe the constraints common to all array elements, and the `contains` keyword to specify the subschemas for each array element individually:

```
{
  "properties": {
    "block": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": {
        "required": [ "type", "parameters" ]
      },
      "oneOf": [
        {
          "contains": {
            "properties": {
              "type": { "const": "countdown" },
              ... more constraints just for the "countdown" type
          }
        },
        { "contains": ... schemas for other types ... },
      ]  
  }
}
```

You can find more information about these keywords [here](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/array.html).

Comment: Tried to get it working, but keep getting error that after "contains" a StartObject or Boolean must follow, and not an array. Could you elaborate a bit further on for example the simplified JSON: 
{
    "blocks": [
        {
            "type": "countdown",
            "parameters": {
                "title": "LIMITED TIME OFFER"
            }
        },
        {
            "type": "text",
            "parameters": {
                "line": "Hello world"
            }
        }
    ]
}

Comment: Oops, I made a mistake, fixing!

Answer (score 0):

You'll want to define your `items` as an `allOf` of `if`/`then`s. This example says, if the type property is the string "countdown" then validate this object as a countdown. You'll need to add one of these `if`/`then` blocks for each block type.

```
{
  "type": "object",
  "properties": {
    "blocks": {
      "type": "array",
      "items": { "$ref": "#/definitions/block" }
    }
  },

  "definitions": {
    "block": {
      "allOf": [
        {
          "if": {
            "type": "object",
            "properties": {
              "type": { "const": "countdown" }
            },
            "required": ["type"]
          },
          "then": { "$ref": "#/definitions/countdown" }
        },
        { ... additional if/thens ... }
      ]
    },
    "countdown": { ... },
    ... additional block type definitions ...
  }
}
```

I don't know how smart IntelliSense is at using JSON Schema to provide hints, but this schema would be the best way to provide the information it would need to support that kind of functionality.

Comment: I added an UPDATE above with my try to get it working. It validates, but it allows too much! IntelliSense would be a big PR in VisualStudioCode...

Comment: Try adding `"additionalProperties": false` to each of your block type definitions.

Comment: Tried everything, read the documentation (and comment) at https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/combining.html?highlight=additionalproperties but where should the `additionalProperties` be placed in `"countdown": {"type": "object","properties": {"title": {"type": "string"}},"required": ["type", "title"]}`?

Comment: It goes at the top level of the "countdown" schema. You should find the example you're looking for here https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/object.html#properties